# How can i solve a limit by precise definition when it has multiple factors on the numerator and a factor in the denominator?

Tags: limits, epsilon-delta

The limit that i'm trying to solve is this one

$$\lim_{{x\to1}}\frac{3x^2+2x+1}{2x-1}={6}$$

I don't know how to handle the case when two factors are in the numerator and one in the denominator

To find the value of $\delta > 0$ in the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of a limit, you typically replace $|f(x) - L|$ in the inequality with $\epsilon$. In the provided expression:

$${|\frac{3x^2+2x+1}{2x-1}-6|}$$

$$\frac{|3x - 7||x - 1|}{|2x - 1|} < \epsilon$$

Comment: @abiessu I did the algebra myself, did I make a mistake?

Comment: @abiessu done the edit

Comment: Why you are trying to find limit at $x=1$, as $f(x)=\frac{3x^2+2x+1}{2x-1}$ is continuous and $f(1)=6$.

Comment: @OM learning real analysis, trying to use the limit precise definition

Comment: My thought is that you only have one term going to zero in the numerator, so that's the one limiting your $\delta$ in the definition approach.  It's been too long and I don't recall what procedure you would do, but perhaps plugging in $x=1$ to the other numerator term would give a useful constant..

Comment: @abiessu oh I'll try that! Thank you very much :)

Comment: Observe the last expression is $\displaystyle \frac{\lvert 3x - 7 \rvert}{\lvert 2x - 1 \rvert} \lvert x - 1 \rvert$. For $x$ near $1$, say between $0.99$ and $1.01$, you can give explicit bounds for the fraction. The latter part, $\lvert x - 1 \rvert$, is exactly what you have control of through $\delta$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The limit that i'm trying to solve is this one
> $$\lim_{{x\to1}}\frac{3x^2+2x+1}{2x-1}={6}$$

The problem becomes trivial if you are allowed to use the following theorem:

Given:

- $~\displaystyle \lim_{x\to a} f(x) = M.$
- $~\displaystyle \lim_{x\to a} g(x) = N \neq 0.$

Then, $~\displaystyle \lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \frac{M}{N}.$

Therefore, I am going to assume that the above approach is **off-limits** and it is required to *go back to basics* and construct an $~\epsilon, ~\delta~$ proof.

---

$\underline{\text{Preliminary Ideas}}$

- Given any function $~f(x),~$ and any positive number $~a,~$ you will have that 
  $|f(x)| < a \iff -a < f(x) < a.$
- Suppose $~0 < a < b,~$ and $~0 < c < d.~$ 
  Further suppose that $~a < f(x) < b,~$ and $~c < g(x) < d.$ 
  Then $~\displaystyle \frac{a}{d} < \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} < \frac{b}{c}.~$ 
  That is, a lower bound is achieved by combining a lower bound of the numerator and an upper bound for the denominator.  Similarly, an upper bound is achieved by combining an upper bound of the numerator and a lower bound for the denominator.
- A common artificial method, in an $~\epsilon,\delta~$ proof, that ensures that all pertinent bounds are positive is to add a constraint to $~\delta,~$ such as (positive) $~\delta~$ must be $~\leq (1/10).$
- The previous bullet point is also handy when trying to relate (for example) $~\delta^2~$ to $~\delta.$  For example, if you are guaranteed that $~0 < \delta \leq (1/10),~$ then you know that $~\delta^2 \leq \dfrac{\delta}{10}.~$

---

$\underline{\text{Formal Proof}}$

Let $~f(x) = 3x^2 + 2x + 1.~~$ Let $~g(x) = 2x - 1.~$

You are given a **fixed** $~\epsilon > 0.~$

You have to construct $~\delta,~$ based on $~\epsilon,~$

such that $~0 < |x-1| < \delta,~$ will **guarantee** that $~\displaystyle \left| ~\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} - 6 ~\right| < \epsilon.$

The $~\epsilon~$ constraint will be satisfied if and only if

$$6 - \epsilon < \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} < 6 + \epsilon. \tag1 $$

In addition to deriving some relationship between $~\delta~$ and $~\epsilon,~$ add the artificial constraint that $~\delta \leq (1/100).~$

So, you have that

$$0 < \delta \leq (1/100) ~~\text{and} ~~1-\delta < x < 1 + \delta. \tag2 $$

Now the problem reduces to deriving a relationship between $~\delta~$ and $~\epsilon~$ so that whenever the constraints in (2) above hold, the constraint in (1) above will also hold.

---

Since $~1-\delta < x < 1 + \delta,~$ 
and since $~\delta^2 < \delta/100,~$ 
you have that

$(1 - \delta)^2 < x^2 < (1 + \delta)^2.$

Therefore, $~1 - 2\delta + \delta^2 < x^2 < 1 + 2\delta + \delta^2.~$

Therefore (rather loosely), $~1 - 3\delta < x^2 < 1 + 3\delta.~$

Therefore, $~3 - 9\delta < 3x^2 < 3 + 9\delta.$

Similarly, $~2 - 2\delta < 2x < 2 + 2\delta.$

Therefore

$$6 - 11\delta < f(x) < 6 + 11\delta.$$

Similarly,

$$1 - 2\delta < g(x) < 1 + 2\delta.$$

Therefore,

$$\frac{6 - 11\delta}{1 + 2\delta} < \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} < \frac{6 + 11\delta}{1 - 2\delta}.$$

Further,

$$\frac{6 - 11\delta}{1 + 2\delta} = 
\frac{6 + 12\delta}{1 + 2\delta} - \frac{23\delta}{1 + 2\delta} = 6 - \frac{23\delta}{1 + 2\delta} \\ > 6 - \frac{23\delta}{1} > 6 - 25\delta.$$

Similarly,

$$\frac{6 + 11\delta}{1 - 2\delta} = \frac{6 - 12\delta}{1 - 2\delta} + \frac{23\delta}{1 - 2\delta} = 6 + \frac{23\delta}{1 - 2\delta} \\ \leq 6 + \frac{23\delta}{0.98} < 6 + 25\delta.$$

Therefore,

$$6 - 25\delta < \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} < 6 + 25\delta.$$

So, let

$$\delta = \min\left( ~\frac{\epsilon}{25}, ~\frac{1}{100} ~\right).$$

This will imply that

$$6 - \epsilon \leq 6 - 25\delta ~~\text{and} ~~6 + 25\delta \leq 6 + \epsilon.$$

It will also imply that $~\delta \leq \dfrac{1}{100}.~$

So, by the analysis given, you will have that whenever $~0 < \delta \leq (1/100),~$ and $~|x - 1| < \delta,~$ you will have that

$$6 - 25\delta < \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} < 6 + 25\delta.$$

Answer (score 2):

> Prove that, $\lim_{{x\to1}}\frac{3x^2+2x+1}{2x-1}={6}$

Given, $\epsilon>0$

Choose, $\delta=\min\{\frac{1}3,\frac{\epsilon}{15}\}$

Suppose, $0<|x-1|<\delta$

Now, $0<|x-1|<\frac{1}3\Rightarrow\frac{2}3<x<\frac{4}3$

$\therefore 2-7<3x-7<4-7\Rightarrow -5<3x-7<-3\Rightarrow|3x-7|<5$

$\therefore \frac{4}3-1<2x-1<\frac{8}3-1\Rightarrow 3>\frac{1}{2x-1}>\frac{3}{5}\Rightarrow\frac{1}{|2x-1|}<3$

Check, $$|\frac{3x^2+2x+1}{2x-1}-{6}|{=\frac{|3x - 7||x - 1|}{|2x - 1|}\\<15\delta\\\le15\cdot\frac{\epsilon}{15}=\epsilon}$$

Comment: how did you get the 1/3 value of e?

Comment: how did you get the 1/3 value of ? *

Comment: @DavidMeléndez you can use any number which useful.You can use $\delta= \min\{\pi,?\}$ the find the value of $?$.

Comment: @DavidMeléndez, As $|x-1|<\delta$, which is the distance between $x$ and $1$ is very tiny so you can easily write $|x-1|<\frac{1}3 \ or \ 1 \ or \ \frac{1}2$. You can learn limit proof [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wf90YjhRTUA&t=1446s).

Answer (score 1):

We want to show according to the definition of the limit
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{3x^2+2x+1}{2x-1}=6
&\Longleftrightarrow\forall \varepsilon>0\ \exists\delta > 0:|x-1|<\delta,x\ne 1\\
&\qquad\qquad\Longrightarrow
\left|\frac{3x^2+2x+1}{2x-1}-6\right|<\varepsilon
\end{align*}

We have $|x-1|<\delta$ under control and can choose $\delta$ as small as we want. As OP has already shown it's a good idea to factor out $|x-1|$ from $|\frac{3x^2+2x+1}{2x-1}-6|$ since then we can use this factor to make the whole expression small (in fact smaller than $\varepsilon$).

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\left|\frac{3x^2+2x+1}{2x-1}-6\right|}&\color{blue}{<\varepsilon}\\
> \left|\frac{3x^2-10x+7}{2x-1}\right|&<\varepsilon\\
> \left|\frac{3(x-1)^2-4x+4}{2x-1}\right|&<\varepsilon\\
> \left|\frac{3(x-1)^2-4(x-1)}{2x-1}\right|&<\varepsilon\\
> \color{blue}{\left|\frac{3x-7}{2x-1}\right||x-1|}&\color{blue}{<\varepsilon}\tag{1}\\
> \end{align*}

In order to find a proper estimation for (1) we may WLOG assume that $x$ is in a small interval with center $1$, let's say
\begin{align*}
x\in\left[\frac{9}{10},\frac{11}{10}\right]\tag{2}
\end{align*}

- Since $|3x-7|$ is decreasing in $\left[\frac{9}{10}, \frac{11}{10}\right]$ we get $|3x-7|\leq \left|3\cdot \frac{9}{10}-7\right|$.
- Since $\left|\frac{1}{2x-1}\right|$ is decreasing in $\left[\frac{9}{10}, \frac{11}{10}\right]$ we get $\left|\frac{1}{2x-1}\right|\leq \left|\frac{1}{2\cdot\frac{9}{10}-1}\right|$.

We can therefore use $\frac{9}{10}$ to estimate the expression in (1).

> We obtain from (1) and (2)
> \begin{align*}
> \left|\frac{3x-7}{2x-1}\right||x-1|&\leq \left|\frac{3\cdot \frac{9}{10}-7}{2\cdot \frac{9}{10}-1}\right||x-1|=\frac{43}{8}|x-1|\tag{3}
> \end{align*}
> In order to get $\frac{43}{8}|x-1|<\varepsilon$ we set $\delta=\frac{4}{43}\varepsilon$ and finally get from (3)
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\left|\frac{3x-7}{2x-1}\right||x-1|}&\leq \frac{43}{8}|x-1|
> \leq \frac{43}{8}\cdot\frac{4}{43}\varepsilon
> =\frac{\varepsilon}{2}
> \color{blue}{<\varepsilon}
> \end{align*}
> and the claim follows.